# How to go to open a new activity after logging into Facebook SDK

Tags: java, android, facebook

I'm going through the Facebook Android SDK (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) and am finding it difficult to understand. I simply want to open a new activity after (successful) login, though the steps show alot of other code and I'm not sure which ones I require. Here's my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/fb_login_btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="496dp" />
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button or_email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        or_email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.or_email);

        or_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }

        });

    }

}
```

**Register.java (for blank activity_register.xml)**

```
public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);    
    }

}
```

So basically, I just want to open `activity_register.xml` after successfully logging in. So i'd imagine I add a new Intent under the `onSuccess()` method. However I'm not sure where exactly I'm supposed to put this code, and also whether it needs the previous code block (the FragmentActivity) in order to work. So If someone could explain to me how each of those 3 code blocks are working in detail. that would be great.

ps: I've already registered my app id and all that so the button is working, I just want it to open a new activity after logging in. Right now it just goes back to `activity_main` after logging in.

Edit: Following code doesn't open up `activity_register`, it just goes back to `activity_main`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button or_email;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        CallbackManager  mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LoginButton mFacebookSignInButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
        mFacebookSignInButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                        //TODO: Use the Profile class to get information about the current user.
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
        );



        or_email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.or_email);

        or_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
            }


        });

    }


}
```

Comment: where is your facebook sdk related code? callbackmanager, result callback etc..

Comment: don't have it, that's why i'm asking. not sure how these parts work and which ones I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

in your activity: Make sure you do

1. Initilize `facebook sdk` and `accessTokenTracker` in `onCreate()`
2. Give permission in your `login Button` and register the callback.
3. In `onSuccess()` method start new Activity
4. Finally override the `onActivityResult()` method and add the `callbackManger.onActivityResult()` with the request code.

   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   ```
   Button or_email;
   CallbackManager  mFacebookCallbackManager;
   private AccessTokenTracker accessTokenTracker;
   private ProfileTracker mProfileTracker;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
       accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
           @Override
           protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldToken, AccessToken newToken) {

           }
       };
       accessTokenTracker.startTracking();

       LoginButton mFacebookSignInButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
       mFacebookSignInButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList(
               "public_profile", "email", "user_birthday", "user_friends"));
       mFacebookSignInButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager, callback);

       or_email = (Button)findViewById(R.id.or_email);

       or_email.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
               MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);
           }


       });

   }

    private FacebookCallback<LoginResult> callback = new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {

       @Override
       public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
           try {
               if (Profile.getCurrentProfile() == null) {
                   mProfileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
                       @Override
                       protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile profile_old, Profile profile_new) {
                           profile = profile_new;
                           Log.v("facebook - profile", profile_new.getFirstName());
                           mProfileTracker.stopTracking();
                       }
                   };
                   mProfileTracker.startTracking();
               } else {
                   profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                   Log.v("facebook - profile", profile.getFirstName());
               }
               Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
               startActivity(intent);
               finish();
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.d("ERROR", e.toString());
           }
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancel() {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }

       @Override
       public void onError(FacebookException e) {
           Log.d("FACEBOOK ERRROR", e.toString());
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Something went wrong!! Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   };


    @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
       mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
   }
   ```

   }

in manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

Make sure your add the app_id in manifest...

Comment: Thanks this works. Are you able to explain how the `onActivityResult()` method is working here? Only bit I don't understand.

Comment: `onActivityResult()` is used to return the result from called actvity to parent  activity...in this case..it goes to the `FacebookActivity` defined in the manifest and then return back to your activity `callbackmnager`...with the request code

Answer (score 0):

> Add this code inside onCreate() method

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    CallbackManager  mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    LoginButton mFacebookSignInButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.fb_login_btn);
    mFacebookSignInButton.registerCallback(mFacebookCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
                    //TODO: Use the Profile class to get information about the current user.
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Just tried this now. It doesn't open up `activity_register`, it just goes back to `activity_main`. Any idea why?

Comment: dude it should go. show me your code what you add in that on success method

Comment: @Zorgan whether your code get into onSucess method or not

Comment: @Zorgan you added Facebook SK?

Comment: Yep. I can click on the FB login button, enter the credentials and login...but it doesn't open the `activity_register`, it just goes back to `activity_main`